# Is it possible to continuously test without disconnecting the socket connection using Jmeter's tcp sampling?

Tags: c++, winforms, tcp, jmeter

I am trying to test the performance of an application server that sends and receives binary data using a tcp socket.(The test server is a windows application)

When I used Jmeter, I had to close the socket for each data transmission to check the result.

But I want to find a function or plugin that can send and receive data without the socket being disconnected.

For example, 700 threads exchange data every 5 minutes for 1 hour, and check if there is any disconnection during the test.

If it is not possible in Jmeter, I want to know a tool that can perform the above test

Can you tell me how to test the performance without disconnecting the socket?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help

I read the user manual of Jmeter, and also read articles on stack overflow, google.

And I did various tests with the server using the TCP sampler.

Answer (score 0):

For binary data there are 2 pre-defined [implementations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler):

> - **BinaryTCPClientImpl**
>
>   This implementation converts the GUI input, which must be a hex-encoded string, into binary, and performs the reverse when reading the response. When reading the response, it reads until the end of message byte, if this is defined by setting the property `tcp.BinaryTCPClient.eomByte`, otherwise until the end of the input stream.
> - **LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl**
>
>   This implementation extends BinaryTCPClientImpl by prefixing the binary message data with a binary length byte. The length prefix defaults to 2 bytes. This can be changed by setting the property `tcp.binarylength.prefix.length`.

The properties can be set under [user.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) or passed via [`-J` command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override).

If none of the implementations matches your needs you will need to come up with your own implementation of the [AbstractTCPClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/AbstractTCPClient.html)

For keeping the connection open between different TCP Samplers there is `Re-use connection` checkbox:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comment :)
first, Transmitting binary data was solved by creating a script in BeanShell PreProcessor.

Comment: second, I tried using Re-use connection option
I made and tested two TCP samplers, and after the TCP connection in the first sampler, I confirmed that if the server does not close the socket, it does not move to the next sampler.
I want to run Sampler sequentially without losing connection. 
Please let me know if you have any possible examples.
I am currently checking if I can use the BeanShell Sampler to solve this by referring to the article below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014596/jmeter-tcp-sampler-not-looping?rq=1